# Installing BlackHat on Ubuntu 16.04 conflicts with Anaconda

Tags: software-installation, python, configure, anaconda

I'm trying to [install BlackHat](https://blackhat.hepforge.org/trac/wiki/BlackHatInstallation) on Ubuntu 16.04.

I have no problem with qd but I can't configure BlackHat.

I got

```
Could not link test program to Python. Maybe the main Python library has been
installed in some non-standard library path. If so, pass it to configure,
via the LDFLAGS environment variable.
Example: ./configure LDFLAGS="-L/usr/non-standard-path/python/lib"
============================================================================
ERROR!
You probably have to install the development version of the Python package
for your distribution.  The exact name of this package varies among them.
============================================================================
```

I found this suggestion

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

but I still got the same problem.

For information, I use Python from Anaconda and the result before the error is

```
checking for python... /home/users/anaconda3/bin/python
checking for a version of Python >= '2.1.0'... yes
checking for the distutils Python package... yes
checking for Python include path... -I/home/users/anaconda3/include/python3.6m
checking for Python library path... -L/home/users/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/config -lpython3.6
checking for Python site-packages path... /home/users/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```